# React.js mixed with asp.net MVC for validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am an experienced .net developer and I am very competent using MVC. I have only just read up a little on react.js today and would like to try and get more into it.

Are there any .net MVC developers or there that have mixed a project up with MVC with good results? Most notably to do with validation.

Normally my C# classes have validation attributes on them. And I can mess around with model state errors to do more custom stuff server side.

How would you mix react validation with MVC? Or can it not be done?

EDIT
Is there anyway to validate in React using the MVC attributes to save duplication of validation?

Comment: You can still add validation attributes to your MVC viewmodel and they will validate server side, as all the model binding/validation etc will work as before.  
Regarding the client side,  there are many libraries out there: http://react-components.com/component/react-validation-mixin, https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react  
Or you could just do it your self and add validation inside the change events and submit button click event on each component, or parent component that contains your child components https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mjcou3UCiBM

Comment: Is there anyway not to duplicate the validation logic?

Comment: There may be, but I haven't found one yet!  as I see it the problem is that you are not using the MVC view engine to render the main body of your view, you are using React.  Plus you are mapping your ViewModel with its annotations into a set of React components that do not know anything about annotations.

Comment: I wonder how clever I could make a T4 template to create a validate class hierarchy on the client side to mimik MVC view models...

Comment: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/react-dot-net is a good starting point with using MVC with React.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having your validation rules server-side, then passing a json object to the client with those validation rules. On the client, you can then create logic to validate these rules, and then once the form is submitted you can run the server-side validation rules and pass back any failed validation to the client.